# VirtualBox guest using Bridged networking unable to obtain DHCP address

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dhcp

I have a computer, called Loki, that works as a virtual machine host and DHCP server. The DHCP daemon is listening on port `eth0`. Part of `/etc/dhcp.conf`:

```
subnet 192.168.13.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.13.140 192.168.13.140;
}

host Windows7VM {
    hardware ethernet 08:00:27:57:C9:69;
    fixed-address 192.168.13.150;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.13.255;
    option routers 192.168.13.1;
}

host TerminalAdam {
    hardware ethernet ...;
    fixed-address 192.168.13.151;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.13.255;
    option routers 192.168.13.1;
}
```

`eth0` is configured like this:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.13.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

There is another computer, called TerminalAdam. The DHCP client configuration of TerminalAdam works fine. Now I need to connect Windows7 virtual machine to this network, so that both TerminalAdam and Windows7VM DHCP clients are configured by Loki's DHCP server.

In VirtualBox VM network settings I choose `bridge`, device `eth0`. When I turn on the VM, I get this in `/var/log/messages.log` several times:

```
Apr 27 14:36:41 localhost dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 08:00:27:57:c9:69 via eth0
Apr 27 14:36:41 localhost dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.13.150 to 08:00:27:57:c9:69 via eth0
```

But in Windows I have "connection to network is not available" in the network adapter status and I cannot connect.

Comment: Are you running the VirtualBox VM guest on the same host that is acting as DHCP server?

Comment: Additionally, is TerminalAdam also a VM guest?

Comment: @uther TerminalAdam is a separate computer, and both VBVM guest and DHCP server run on the same machine.

Comment: For completeness, would you edit your question with that information? It will help you get a higher quality answer.

Comment: @uther Yes, I added that information just after your edit

Comment: hi guys sorry for interrupt, I need a help on dhcp server. Could you check this one http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140387/pxeboot-client-not-getting-ip-address-from-the-dhcp-server

Answer (score 1):

I have observed the same on VirtualBox: Sometimes DHCP does not work at all, sometimes it takes some time until the DHCP-request "goes through". Try to emulate a different network card.