# Pxeboot: Client not getting ip address from the DHCP Server

Tags: dhcp, pxe, isc-dhcpd

I am Working on Pxeboot. I have a Ubuntu system as KVM and in that system I installed Virtual machine manager.

I also installed Ubuntu in the virtual machine.

Before I start my virtual machine, I attached the Virtual network interface.

```
Source device: Host device eth0:macvtap
Device model : Hypervisor default
Mac Address  : 00:22:11:01:22:55
Source mode  : private
```

I installed DHCP server in the VM:

```
# apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

And configured in the `dhcpd.conf` file:

```
allow booting;
allow bootp;

filename "pxelinux.0"

subnet 10.5.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.5.5.5 10.5.5.100;
  option domain-name-servers ns1.testworld.local.net;
  option domain-name "testworld.local.net";
  option routers 10.5.5.1;
  option broadcast-address 10.5.5.254;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
 }

host pxebootserver {
  hardware ethernet 00:22:11:01:22:55      
  fixed-address 10.5.5.1
 }
```

When I restart the isc-dhcp-server, I got this errors in syslog:

```
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd: 
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd: No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd: 
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd: 
Jul  2 20:06:19 ubuntu dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Jul  2 20:10:26 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  2 20:10:35 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
Jul  2 20:10:56 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  2 20:11:08 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
Jul  2 20:11:25 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  2 20:11:35 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  2 20:11:47 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16
Jul  2 20:12:03 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  2 20:12:14 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  2 20:12:23 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  2 20:12:34 ubuntu dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  2 20:12:37 ubuntu dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  2 20:12:37 ubuntu dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Even clients cannot discover the dhcp server.

Which virtual network adapter do I have to enable in the Client VM?

Comment: can you please post the output of `ip addr` on the dhcp server?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that `KVM` will likely use `dnsmasq` to provide addresses. The address ranges are configured in the network definition.  It should not be necessary to install your own DHCP server.

The `isc-dhcp-server` is likely trying to listen on a `eth0` as a default.  It not unusual to have a point-to-point address on your Internet interface (usually `eth0`).   If not it is likely using an address in the `192.168.0.0/16` address range provided by your router.

I configure my VMs using a fixed address on a bridge device which is not connected to any external interfaces.  However, if you do have a router you may want to configure your `KVM` bridge to include the `eth0`.